# Organising multiple columns into a row based on another column

Tags: r, multiple-columns

Absolute R newbie, and I know this should be simple, but I have spent 2 hours without any success.

How can I convert my dataframe from this (First 6 lines of dataframe)

```
Symbol  AF  wave
CUX1    0.0975  1
CUX1    0.0337  3
CUX1    0.0217  4
LUC7L2  0.0488  1
LUC7L2  0.0515  3
LUC7L2  0.0422  4
```

to something like this?

```
Symbol  AF  wave 1  wave 2  wave 3  wave 4
CUX1    0.0975  0.0975  NA  0.0337  0.0217
LUC7L2  0.0337  0.0488  NA  0.0515  0.0422
```

Hi Akron,

with your advice I get something like this:

```
Symbol  AF  wave 1  wave 2  wave 3  wave 4
CUX1    0.0975  0.0975  NA  NA  NA
LUC7L2  0.0337  0.0337  NA  NA  NA
CUX1    0.0975  NA  0.0337  NA  NA
LUC7L2  0.0337  NA  0.0515  NA  NA
CUX1    0.0975  NA  NA  0.082   NA
LUC7L2  0.0337  NA  NA  0.0781  NA
```

So almost there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to first `complete` the missing 'wave' and then do the `pivot_wider` to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(wave = str_c('wave', wave)) %>%
    complete(wave = str_c('wave', 1:4)) %>%
    mutate(rn = rowid(wave)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = wave, values_from = AF) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Symbol)) %>%
    select(-rn)
# A tibble: 2 x 5
#  Symbol  wave1 wave2  wave3  wave4
#  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 CUX1   0.0975    NA 0.0337 0.0217
#2 LUC7L2 0.0488    NA 0.0515 0.0422
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Symbol = c("CUX1", "CUX1", "CUX1", "LUC7L2", "LUC7L2", 
"LUC7L2"), AF = c(0.0975, 0.0337, 0.0217, 0.0488, 0.0515, 0.0422
), wave = c(1L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Dear Akrun, that seems to be almost the answer, but my dataframe output looks like this:

Comment: @biologist81 please check the ouptut